# Don't show \headmark if the page starts with a heading

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage, scrreprt

Is there a way to hide the \headmark if the page starts with a chapter or a section, but still show the graphic in the header?

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV=10,ngerman,headings=normal,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,index=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=1pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles

\automark{chapter}
\automark*{section}

\ihead{\headmark}
\rohead{\raisebox{0pt}[\ht\strutbox]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1cm]{Test}}} 
\ofoot{\pagemark} 

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\begin{document} 
\chapter{Chapter ONE}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Section ONE}
\blindtext[5]
\blindtext[1]
\section{Section TWO}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

The headmarks on page 1 and 4 of the example should be hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For chapter pages, this can easily be done by setting up the `plain` page style in an appropriate way. Remove your redefinition of `\chapterpagestyle` and use the starred variants to set the header and footer where you want to affect `plain` pages as well.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, DIV=10, headings=normal]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline=1pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}

%\automark{chapter} <- Doesn't do anything for one-sided documents.
\automark*{section}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\rohead*{\raisebox{0pt}[\ht\strutbox]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1cm]{Test}}} 
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter ONE}
\blindtext[5]

\section{Section ONE}
\blindtext[5]
\blindtext[1]

\section{Section TWO}
\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

---

Now, your wish to do the same for `\section`s which start on a new page is not advisable, as it is rather inconsistent to sometimes find the header on the page where the section starts (when it's not at the start of the page) and sometimes not. I would recommend not doing this.

If you insist, however, it can of course be done, for example like this. I use labels before and after every section heading to detect page breaks and add the page to a list if so (actually, the page before the section, but let's not dwell on that). At every page, I check if the current page is in that list and use `\thispagestyle` if so.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, DIV=10, headings=normal]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline=1pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{bophook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%\automark{chapter} <- Doesn't do anything for one-sided documents.
\automark*{section}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\rohead*{\raisebox{0pt}[\ht\strutbox]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1cm]{Test}}} 
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\makeatletter
  \AtBeginPage{%
    \@maybe@current@page@plain
  }
  \def\@maybe@current@page@plain{%
    \begingroup
      \@check@if@current@page@plain
      \if@tempswa
        \thispagestyle{plain}%
      \fi
    \endgroup
  }
  \def\@check@if@current@page@plain{\@tempswafalse}
  \def\@check@if@ref@is@current@page@#1{%
    \ifnum\arabic{page}=\getpagerefnumber{#1}\relax
      \@tempswatrue
    \fi
  }
  \AddtoDoHook{heading/preinit/section}{\begingroup\advance\c@section 1\relax\label{before@section@\thesection}\endgroup}
  \AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/section}{%
    \label{at@section@\thesection}%
    \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{before@section@\thesection}<\getpagerefnumber{at@section@\thesection}\relax
      \xappto\@check@if@current@page@plain{\noexpand\@check@if@ref@is@current@page@{before@section@\thesection}}%
    \fi
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter ONE}
\blindtext[5]

\section{Section ONE}
\blindtext[5]
\blindtext[1]

\section{Section TWO}
\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this costly solution!
It works, but in my real document, i use sometimes "\newpage" to start a section on top of the next page. And in this cases your detector fails and the sections will get a headmark.
I can reproduce it, by deleting the \newpage-command and setting some normal text until the page is full.

Comment: @kolja Do you want _every_ section to start on a new page? In that case it is much better to declare it that way globally (which also eliminates the need for a workaround like in my answer).

Comment: No, not on every Section. Only there, where the beginning of the section needs a full page.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for chapter pages:

Remove `\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}` which changes the page style of chapter pages from `plain` to `scrheadings`. Then you can adjust the `plain` style adding option `plainheadsepline` (if there should be a head sepline on plain pages too) and using the starred commands `\rohead*` and `\ofoot*`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,DIV=10,ngerman,headings=normal,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,index=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=1pt,
  plainheadsepline% <- head sepline also on plain pages
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles

\automark{chapter}
\automark*{section}

\ihead{\headmark}
\rohead*{\raisebox{0pt}[\ht\strutbox]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1cm]{Test}}}% * added
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% * added 

%\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}% <- remove this to use plain style for chapter pages

\begin{document} 
\chapter{Chapter ONE}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Section ONE}
\blindtext[5]
\blindtext[1]
\section{Section TWO}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Your second wish is completely unusual, because sections are not as highlighted headings as chapters. I guess it will be really difficult to automatically know if a section is starting a new page.